# Where is $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess state stored between calls (and how can it be reset)?

Tags: powershell

Consider the following contrived example:

```powershell
function Test-ProcessContinue {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='High')]
    Param()

    for ($i = 1; $i -le 3; $i++) {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$i", "Process")) {
            Write-Output "Processing $i"
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "No chosen"
        }
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i -le 3; $i++) {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$i", "Process")) {
            Write-Output "Processing $i"
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "No chosen"
        }
    }

    $yta = $false; $nta = $false
    for ($i = 1; $i -le 3; $i++) {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue("$i", "Continue", [ref]$yta, [ref]$nta) -or $yta) {
            Write-Output "Continuing with $i"
        }
        elseif ($nta) {
            Write-Verbose "No to all chosen"
            break
        }
        else {
            Write-Verbose "No chosen"
        }
    }
}
```

...and one of its potential outputs:

```
PS C:\> Test-ProcessContinue -Verbose

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Process" on target "1".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): a
Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3
Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3

Continue
1
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): a
Continuing with 1
Continuing with 2
Continuing with 3
```

In the case of the `ShouldContinue` loop (third `for` loop), I can see that the overload with the two by-reference boolean parameters is responsible for storing whether the end-user chose *Yes to All* or *No to All* into those two booleans.

However, in the case of the two `ShouldProcess` blocks (first two `for` loops), how is this state preserved?

In particular, in between the first two `ShouldProcess` blocks, how could I check if *Yes to All* or *No to All* were specified and/or what would I need to reset or clear in order to make the second `ShouldProcess` block ask for confirmation again?

(Favouring `ShouldContinue` over `ShouldProcess` is an *option* for fine-grained control, but it appears to lose the native/built-in support for `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'll address `$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue`. This is basically a way to prompt *on your own* regardless of Confirm preferences.

`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess` on the other hand, doesn't always prompt. It takes into account the `ConfirmImpact` (which you set to `High`), and the `$ConfirmPreference` automatic variable, which defaults to `High`. The valid values are `None`, `Low`, `Medium`, and `High` and are meant to indicate how much of an impact a change has, so when `$ConfirmPreference`'s value is equal to or less than a command's `ConfirmImpact` value, then `ShouldProcess` will prompt.

I know this isn't your direct question, but the background is important for answering what you should do.

The direct question: "where is the answer stored?" has a boring answer: [it's stored in an internal variable in the class that defines the `ShouldProcess` method](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c43beccaa2f0d6295aac1e977f56f5bd50c73f3e/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MshCommandRuntime.cs#L3423).

So, no, you can't get at it yourself, unfortunately.

But that brings us back to `.ShouldContinue`, which can take those references and store those values for you, so when you want the values, and want to be able to make decisions with them, you should use `.ShouldContinue`.

But, you should really use both. Because they do different things.

`.ShouldProcess` isn't just responsible for confirmation prompts, it's also responsible for handling `-WhatIf`/`$WhatIfPreference`; when you say your command `SupportsShouldProcess` you are also saying it supports `-WhatIf`. If you don't use `.ShouldProcess`, you'll get into the situation of having commands that appear to be safe but actually take action anyway.

So a pattern of something like this would cover your bases:

```
if ($PSCmdet.ShouldProcess('thing', 'do')) {
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue('prompt')) {
        # do it
    }
}
```

Problem with this goes back to your confirm impact and preferences. If those line up, or if the user invoked your command with `-Confirm`, you'll be prompting twice: once in the `.ShouldProcess` and then again in the `.ShouldContinue`.

That kind of sucks unfortunately.

I wrote a thing that seems to work around this. It's predicated first on a function that allows you to run an arbitrary scriptblock with confirmation, so that you can still run `.ShouldProcess` while suppressing its prompt.

Then it also tries to calculate whether a prompt is needed or not, and then selectively call `.ShouldContinue`. I didn't demonstrate storing or resetting the yesToAll and noToAll vars because you already know how to do that.

This is mainly to demo a pattern that could be used to adhere to standard confirmation prompt semantics, with discoverability, support for the `-Confirm` parameter, `$ConfirmPreference`, and `ConfirmImpact`, while maintaining support for `-Verbose` and `-WhatIf`.

```
function Test-Should {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param()

    Begin {
        $local:ShouldConfirm = $ConfirmPreference -ne [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::None -and 
                               $ConfirmPreference -le [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::High # hard coded :(

        function Invoke-CommandWithConfirmation {
            [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
            param(
                [Parameter(Mandatory)]
                [ScriptBlock]
                $ScriptBlock
            )

            Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
        }
    }

    Process {
        if (Invoke-CommandWithConfirmation -ScriptBlock { $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('target', 'action') } -Confirm:$false ) {
            if (-not $local:ShouldConfirm -or $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue('query', 'caption')) {
                'Hi' | Write-Host
                'Hello' | Write-Verbose
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Invocations:

```
Test-Should
Test-Should -Confirm
Test-Should -Confirm:$false
Test-Should -Verbose
Test-Should -Verbose -WhatIf
Test-Should -WhatIf -Confirm
Test-Should -WhatIf -Confirm:$false
```

And so on, with different values of `$ConfirmPreference` and different values for the command's `ConfirmImpact`.

The one thing annoying is the value I marked as hard coded: it has to match what you set as the confirm impact for that command.

[It turns out it's kind of a pain in the ass to get at that value programmatically](http://mctexpert.blogspot.com/2014/12/list-impact-level-of-all-powershell.html), but maybe you could work that in in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly an extension of @briantist answer, but I was struggling with how to fully implement this for a while but I have gotten it working the way I want and wanted to share in case anyone else has a similar goal as me. I am hoping to turn this into a complete class that does all of this for me, but baby steps.

```
Function New-Function {
    [CmdletBinding(
        ConfirmImpact='None',
        DefaultParameterSetName="Default",
        HelpURI="",
        SupportsPaging=$False,
        SupportsShouldProcess=$True,
        PositionalBinding=$True
    )] Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $Items,
        $Impact = 'Medium',
        [Switch]$Force
    )

    Begin {
        $PSCmdlet.GetDynamicParameters()
        If (-Not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Verbose')) {
            $VerbosePreference = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue('VerbosePreference')
        }

        If (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Confirm')) {
            $ConfirmPreference = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue('ConfirmPreference')
        }

        If (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf')) {
            $WhatIfPreference = $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue('WhatIfPreference')
        }

        New-Variable -Name YesToAll -Value $False -Verbose:$False -Confirm:$False -WhatIf:$False
        New-Variable -Name NoToAll  -Value $False -Verbose:$False -Confirm:$False -WhatIf:$False
        
        [Bool]$Local:ShouldConfirm = $Force -OR $ConfirmPreference -ne [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::None -and $ConfirmPreference -le [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::$Impact
        $Local:ShouldProcess = ([Scriptblock]::Create(("Function ShouldProcess{{[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='{0}')]Param()`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('{1}','{2}')}};ShouldProcess -Confirm:`$False" -f $Impact,'Target','Action')))
        $Local:ShouldContinue = ([ScriptBlock]::Create(("Function ShouldContinue {{[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='{0}')]Param()New-Variable -Name YesToAll -Value `$PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('YesToAll') -Verbose:`$False -Confirm:`$False -WhatIf:`$False;New-Variable -Name NoToAll -Value `$PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('NoToAll') -Verbose:`$False -Confirm:`$False -WhatIf:`$False;`$PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue('{1}','{2}',[Ref]`$YesToAll,[Ref]`$NoToAll);Set-Variable -Name YesToAll -Value `$YesToAll -Scope 1 -Confirm:`$False -Verbose:`$False -WhatIf:`$False;Set-Variable -Name NoToAll  -Value `$NoToAll -Scope 1 -Confirm:`$False -Verbose:`$False -WhatIf:`$False;}};ShouldContinue" -f $Impact,'Target','Action')))
    }
 
    Process {
        ForEach ($Item in $Items) {
            IF ((Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock $Local:ShouldProcess) -eq $True) {
                If ($Force -or $Local:ShouldConfirm -eq $False -or (Invoke-Command -NoNewScope -ScriptBlock $Local:ShouldContinue)) {
                    IF ($Local:Force) {
                        Write-Verbose -Message 'Force'
                    } ElseIf ($Local:YesToAll -eq $True) {
                        Write-Verbose -Message 'YesToAll'
                    } Else {
                        Write-Verbose -Message 'Yes'
                    }
                    Write-Host $Item
                } Else {
                    If ($Local:NoToAll -eq $True) {
                        Write-Verbose -Message 'NoToAll'
                    } Else {
                        Write-Verbose -Message 'No'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    End {

    }
}
$ConfirmPreference = 'High'
'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' | New-Function -Impact Medium
```